# the jquery theme switcher "loadTheme" doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-theme

I want when page loaded ,load jquery ui theme 'vader'

so the code:

```
    $('#switcher').themeswitcher({
        loadTheme: 'vader',
        width: 160
    });
```

but the page can only load the theme I selected last time

I have collect all theme folders in localhost,I doesn't change the theme folder name

and I can choose different theme normally and correctly,the element's style could changed,but it can not just load the theme I appointed

So what's wrong with my code? how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: When you call this code? Is it in $(document).ready(); ?

Comment: @YNhat:yup,of course it in $(document).ready();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the loadTheme-option is overriden by an existing cookie.

Try:

```
$('#switcher').themeswitcher({loadTheme: 'Vader', cookieName:'', width: 160});
```

(also note the uppercase V in Vader, the theme-names are case-sensitive)